# Vue: Bind Change event to dynamically inserted content

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, vue.js

I have a Vue app which get an html from API that contains some code like `<div class="play-video"> <input type="text" class="input-1"/></div>`

Calling the API with axios via a promise, it is inserted into the dom something like:

`<div v-if="content" v-html="content"></div>`

How can I bind on change events to the children inputs with the .input-1 class?

Answer (score 2):

You could query the container for those inputs, and add an event handler to each:

1. Apply a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) (named `container`) on the container `div`:

   ```html
   <div ref="container">
   ```
2. Add a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on `content` that queries the container (via [`this.$refs.container.querySelectorAll()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)) for `<input class="input-1">`, and adds an event handler to each input. Note that the handler needs to wait until [`$nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick), after which the `v-html` directive would have had a chance to update.

   ```js
   export default {
     watch: {
       content: {
         async handler(content) {
           // wait til v-html directives takes effect
           await this.$nextTick()

           this.$refs.container
             .querySelectorAll('.input-1')
             .forEach((input) => input.addEventListener('change', this.onInputChange))
         },
         immediate: true,
       },
     },
     methods: {
       onInputChange(e) {
         console.log('input change')
       },
     },
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/binding-event-handler-to-dynamic-html-nhm7j?file=/src/components/DynamicContent.vue)

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that rise to the top for me:

1. From inside a vue app, use vanilla javascript to append those nodes to the DOM and then query for their inputs and add event handlers. Since you're inside the Vue app you can write the handlers to interact with Vue components. Or you could probably do something fancy with vuex getters returning those elements (if they're still attached to the document).
2. Use [Vue.compile](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) to create render functions from the html or add an [async omponent](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components). However, this will only work if you have a robust way to add `@change="doSomething"` to the template. For this reason, I'd probably should go with option 1) unless you control the source of the templates.

Whichever you do, keep malicious injections in mind.

```js
const someHtml = '<div class="play-video"><input type="text" class="input-1"/></div>'

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    const dynamicContent = document.createElement('div');
    dynamicContent.innerHTML = someHtml;
    dynamicContent.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change',
      e => this.inputValue = e.target.value);
    this.$refs.container.appendChild(dynamicContent);
  },
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'Vue',
      inputValue: ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>type something below then click this text</div>
  <div ref="container"></div>
  <div>The user entered: {{inputValue}}</div>
</div>
```